# JQuery one ajax call inside another with load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I have the following code & I know what's the issue but I just can't figure out how to fix it. Basically I have an ajax call and on success I would like to have another ajax call using `.load()`. The issue is that in the second ajax call I don't get the result from the first one. Do I have to use Promise?

```js
$('select[name="product-pagination"]').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $( this ).closest( 'form.search' ).submit();
  var select = $(this);
  var form = select.closest('form.search');
  $('.products-container').addClass('loading');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (textStatus === 'success') {
        $('.products-container').removeClass('loading');
        $('#products-container-inner').load(window.location.href + ' #products-container-inner > *', '');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What result? It looks like you are loading the page you are on ???

Comment: Yes, I'm submitting the form within the same page (reloading) & I would like to get the partial content for the 1st ajax call. You are correct it should be `+` not `,` I did a typo while adding the code here. When I do `console.log` on the `load` line I get new content that comes from the 1st ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this before without any success all I got is the deprecated notice for XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: When I do this `$( '#products-container-inner' ).load( window.location.href + ' #products-container-inner > *', '', function() { alert( 'Loaded.' ) });` for testing I first get the `loading` class removed and maybe 3-4 seconds after that I get the alert `Loaded`msg . I feel like the page reload isn't fully completed.

Comment: No need to use async false

Comment: @RohitMittal that's a bad suggestion. Firstly `async: false` is deprecated due to the poor user experience it creates (locks the browser UI during requests) and may therefore be removed soon from browsers entirely. Secondly it won't make any difference in this case - the second ajax request is started within the "success" callback of the first, so it can never be triggered until the first ajax finishes. If you think async:false would help here then you need to improve your understanding of AJAX.

Comment: @krasenslavov is it me or is making the second request a bit unnecessary? Why doesn't the first request return the necessary updated HTML in its response? Then you can just update your div with that directly.

Comment: You could be right, maybe my logic and approach a totally wrong here. I will try to think of another solution, btw. this is for wp + woo products table pagination.

Comment: Thanks @aDyson for correcting me. Really appreciate